# Given a 2D array, find the object within where object[1] is equal to some string x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of Arrays:
[ ['ALC', '10.0', 240001], ['ALC','2401', 240010] ]

How do I get the entire second array entry when I have the string '2401'

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
tests = [ ['ALC', '10.0', 240001], ['ALC','2401', 240010] ]
print(list(filter(lambda x: '2401' in x, tests)))
```

`Filter` filters out an item based on boolean criteria you provide. 
So here the critera we are providing is `2401 in x`.

The `x` in lambda, represents one element of the list your provided as an argument. The list provided is `tests`, (at the right-end of the lambda function).

Here are some more examples of `filter`

http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Here is the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: Appreciate the comment! Here is a bonus question... What if instead of just '2401' I have a list of desired strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
arraylist = [ ['ALC', '10.0', 240001], ['ALC','2401', 240010] ]
for array in arraylist:
    if '2401' in array:
        print array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension to get a list of matches:

```
data = [ ['ALC', '10.0', 240001], ['ALC','2401', 240010] ]

search = '2401'
filtered_data = [entry for entry in data if entry[1] == search]
```

`filtered_data` contains `[['ALC', '2401', 240010]]`.

If there are multiple matches:

```
data = [ ['ALC', '10.0', 240001], ['ALC','2401', 240010], ['ALC','2401', 240011], ['ALC','2401', 240012] ]

search = '2401'
filtered_data = [entry for entry in data if entry[1] == search]
```

`filtered_data` will contain `[['ALC', '2401', 240010], ['ALC', '2401', 240011], ['ALC', '2401', 240012]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over the main list and then use the `in` operator to check if the "term" you are looking for is inside of the "sub-list"

```
def find_sublist_with_term(l, term):
    for subl in l:
        if term in subl:
            return subl

mylist = [ ['ALC', '10.0', 240001], ['ALC','2401', 240010] ]
found = find_sublist_with_term(mylist, "2401")
```

Comment: To improve the long-term usefulness of your answer, could you add some description of what is doing, how it works, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

A generator approach, also capable to find more than one match:

```
def find_subarray(arr, s):
    for a in arr:
        if a[1]==s:
            yield a
```

Test:

```
loa = [ ['ALC', '10.0', 240001], ['ALC','2401', 240010], ['ALD','2401', 240010], ['ALF','2401', 240010]]
result = find_subarray(loa, "2401")
print(list(result))
# [['ALC', '2401', 240010], ['ALD', '2401', 240010], ['ALF', '2401', 240010]]
```